# need help looking for environment variables generated by Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am running a Docker source codes which has a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM node:14-slim as build

# install node-gyp dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils cron g++ make python

# add pin script
WORKDIR /
ADD scripts/pinVersions.js scripts/cleanup.sh ./
RUN chmod +x /cleanup.sh

# build server
WORKDIR /app
ADD packages/server .
RUN node /pinVersions.js && yarn && yarn build && /cleanup.sh

# build worker
WORKDIR /worker
ADD packages/worker .
RUN node /pinVersions.js && yarn && yarn build && /cleanup.sh

FROM couchdb:3.2.1
# TARGETARCH can be amd64 or arm e.g. docker build --build-arg TARGETARCH=amd64
ARG TARGETARCH amd64
#TARGETBUILD can be set to single (for single docker image) or aas (for azure app service)
# e.g. docker build --build-arg TARGETBUILD=aas ....
ARG TARGETBUILD single
ENV TARGETBUILD $TARGETBUILD

COPY --from=build /app /app
COPY --from=build /worker /worker

ENV \
  APP_PORT=4001 \
  ARCHITECTURE=amd \
  BUDIBASE_ENVIRONMENT=PRODUCTION \
  CLUSTER_PORT=80 \
  # CUSTOM_DOMAIN=budi001.custom.com \
  DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT=docker \
  MINIO_URL=http://localhost:9000 \
  POSTHOG_TOKEN=phc_fg5I3nDOf6oJVMHSaycEhpPdlgS8rzXG2r6F2IpxCHS \
  REDIS_URL=localhost:6379 \
  SELF_HOSTED=1 \
  TARGETBUILD=$TARGETBUILD \
  WORKER_PORT=4002 \
  WORKER_URL=http://localhost:4002 \
  APPS_URL=http://localhost:4001

# These secret env variables are generated by the runner at startup
# their values can be overriden by the user, they will be written
# to the .env file in the /data directory for use later on
#  REDIS_PASSWORD=something\
#  COUCHDB_PASSWORD=something \
#  COUCHDB_USER=something \
#  COUCH_DB_URL=http://something@localhost:5984 \
#  INTERNAL_API_KEY=something \
#  JWT_SECRET=something \
#  MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=something \
#  MINIO_SECRET_KEY=something \
```

There is a runner.sh that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a ENV_VARS=("COUCHDB_USER" "COUCHDB_PASSWORD" "MINIO_ACCESS_KEY" "MINIO_SECRET_KEY" "INTERNAL_API_KEY" "JWT_SECRET" "REDIS_PASSWORD")
if [ -f "/data/.env" ]; then
    export $(cat /data/.env | xargs)
fi
# first randomise any unset environment variables
for ENV_VAR in "${ENV_VARS[@]}"
do
    temp=$(eval "echo \$$ENV_VAR")
    if [[ -z "${temp}" ]]; then
        eval "export $ENV_VAR=$(uuidgen | sed -e 's/-//g')"
    fi
done
if [[ -z "${COUCH_DB_URL}" ]]; then
    export COUCH_DB_URL=http://$COUCHDB_USER:$COUCHDB_PASSWORD@localhost:5984
fi
if [ ! -f "/data/.env" ]; then
    touch /data/.env
    for ENV_VAR in "${ENV_VARS[@]}"
    do
        temp=$(eval "echo \$$ENV_VAR")
        echo "$ENV_VAR=$temp" >> /data/.env
    done
fi

# make these directories in runner, incase of mount
mkdir -p /data/couch/dbs /data/couch/views
chown couchdb:couchdb /data/couch /data/couch/dbs /data/couch/views
redis-server --requirepass $REDIS_PASSWORD &
/opt/clouseau/bin/clouseau &
/minio/minio server /data/minio &
/docker-entrypoint.sh /opt/couchdb/bin/couchdb &
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
if [[ ! -z "${CUSTOM_DOMAIN}" ]]; then
    # Add monthly cron job to renew certbot certificate
    echo -n "* * 2 * * root exec /app/letsencrypt/certificate-renew.sh ${CUSTOM_DOMAIN}" >> /etc/cron.d/certificate-renew
    chmod +x /etc/cron.d/certificate-renew
    # Request the certbot certificate
    /app/letsencrypt/certificate-request.sh ${CUSTOM_DOMAIN}
fi

/etc/init.d/nginx restart
pushd app
pm2 start --name app "yarn run:docker"
popd
pushd worker
pm2 start --name worker "yarn run:docker"
popd
sleep 10
curl -X PUT ${COUCH_DB_URL}/_users
curl -X PUT ${COUCH_DB_URL}/_replicator
sleep infinity
```

Now I want to know what is the value of the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD which is supposed to be randomly generated.

- I tried `docker exec -it containername /bin/bash` and `printenv`, it is not there.
- I tried `docker exec -it containername /bin/bash` and look for the /data folder, couldnt see any .env file

Can any docker expert advise where will I find the environment variables?

Comment: Maybe need to run the first part of runner.sh to see what gets set, once you bash into it? Cheers!

Comment: @rogerdpack If I run the runner.sh again, manually, I can indeed see the .env file appearing. But it will cause a lot of problem like 2 copies of the servers are now running concurrently etc.

Comment: Would this setup be easier to run in a virtual machine with a more traditional init system?  Or could you use a tool like Docker Compose to run nine separate single-process containers?  Getting a debugging shell with `docker exec` won't see the environment variables that are only set within the main process, but if you make an interactive login to a VM it will read the standard system dotfiles.

Comment: @DavidMaze what's the command to interactive login, if not using docker exec? sorry still learning docker

Comment: The normal setup is that a Docker container is a wrapper around a single process.  So if you think of the container as equivalent to, say, the Redis server; when do you need to perform an interactive login to that single process?  In normal operation you shouldn't usually need `docker exec` (though it is a pretty useful debugging tool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a Docker question: nothing that is happening here is docker-specific.

---

The environment variables are set in `runner.sh`. There are two places those variables are set:

1. If `/data/.env` exists at the beginning of the script, those variables are exported to the environment:

   ```
   if [ -f "/data/.env" ]; then
       export $(cat /data/.env | xargs)
   fi
   ```
2. Variables in the list `ENV_VARS` that weren't previously set are
   set to random values, which are then exported to the environment:

   ```
   for ENV_VAR in "${ENV_VARS[@]}"
   do
      temp=$(eval "echo \$$ENV_VAR")
      if [[ -z "${temp}" ]]; then
          eval "export $ENV_VAR=$(uuidgen | sed -e 's/-//g')"
      fi
   done
   ```

You won't see them in `docker exec -it containername /bin/bash` because that shell isn't a child of `runner.sh`, so of course it won't see environment variables set by that script.

It looks as if `runner.sh` should create `/data/.env` unconditionally,
so it's not clear why you're not seeing it. Note that you won't see
`.env` with a simple `ls`; you would need to run `ls -A /.data`, for example.

---

**Update**

If I follow the [image build instructions](https://github.com/Budibase/budibase/tree/develop/hosting/single#build-image) and then start the image (`docker run --name budibase budibase:latest`), then when I `docker exec` into the resulting container I see `/data/.env`:

```
$ docker exec budibase ls -A /data
.env
couch
minio
```

Comment: strange, ls -a also not showing the .env file

Comment: If you want to provide a runnable example I'm happy to take a closer look, but as it stands I can't build an image from that Dockerfile because it relies on content that I don't have available locally.

Comment: sure! it is an open source codebase. I followed these steps to run a docker container on DigitalOcean droplet: https://github.com/Budibase/budibase/tree/develop/hosting/single.

Comment: Seems to work as I expected; see my update.

Comment: thanks for your time to give it a try. I haven't figured out why I still cant see the .env file on digitalocean droplet. will spend some time to continue trying, will mark the answer as correct for now cheers.